# How to display a popup notification on user time selection in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new to Android.I have to display the popup notification on user time selection using time picker when the notification toggle button is on and also when the app is closed it shows the notification. Can anyone help?

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: A popup notification is displaying.But I don't know how to display the notification when the toggle button is on and when the toggle button is off it shouldn't display the notification.I want code for this concept.Below is my code

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Utils {

    public static NotificationManager mManager;


    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void generateNotification(Context context){

        android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder nb= new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        nb.setContentTitle("Some text here");
        nb.setContentText("Some text here");
        nb.setTicker("Take a look");
        nb.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        nb.setAutoCancel(true);



        //get the bitmap to show in notification bar
        Bitmap bitmap_image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle s = new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap_image);
        s.setSummaryText("some text here");
        nb.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
               nb .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        nb.setStyle(s);



        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder TSB = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        TSB.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        TSB.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                TSB.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        nb.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        nb.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(11221, nb.build());


    }
}
```